# What will be the return status in the following shell script

Tags: shell

i have two shell scripts:

### script1.sh

```
echo "`date` : DATE"
exit 0;
```

### script2.sh

```
./scripts1.sh
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    reboot;
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

What should be the result. Ideally it should have been "reboot" , however on some execution i got the "failed" message too. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Is that a typo in the second script? The first script is called "script1.sh", but in your second you're calling "scripts1.sh" -- note the extra 's'.

Comment: What is the value of $? when you get "Failed"

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the second script calls a script named, "scripts1.sh," but the name of the first script is, "script1.sh." In other words, you have an extra "s" in the name of that first script, when you reference it in the second.

Comment: Sorry that was a just a typing mistake. The script called is exactly the one present.